# makefile execute after modify the input or only not executed input

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to do a makefile for run some programs. Every time I run that script all the file are processed also if the file are not changed. I'm sure there is a problem on my code but I don't understand where I made the mistakes.

```
RDIR=RAW
OUTDIR=Fusion_res/kallisto
RFILES:=$(wildcard $(RDIR)/*_R1_001.fastq.gz)
DATABASE=/home/sbsuser/databases/Kallsto_hg38_87
OUTFILE=$(patsubst %_R1_001.fastq.gz,%_R2_001.fastq.gz,$(RFILES))
OUTKAL=$(patsubst $(RDIR)/%_R1_001.fastq.gz,$(OUTDIR)/%,$(RFILES)) 
.PHONY: clean all 

all: $(OUTFILE) $(RFILES) $(OUTDIR) $(OUTKAL)


#$(OUTKAL) $(OUTFILE): $(RDIR)/%._R1_001.fastq.gz   
#   echo "kallisto  quant -i" $(DATABASE)/transcripts.idx -b 100 -o $@ --fusion $< $(OUTFILE)

$(OUTDIR)/%: $(RDIR)/%_R1_001.fastq.gz $(OUTFILE)
      kallisto  quant -i $(DATABASE)/transcripts.idx -b 100  --fusion --rf-stranded -o $@ $(RDIR)/$*_R1_00
1.fastq.gz   $(RDIR)/$*_R2_001.fastq.gz 



$(OUTDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)


clean::
    $(RM) -rf $(OUTDIR)
```

I suppose if the found some change on the input file and on the output execute the command. I don't know why every time force re-run. In some case Is that I want but I wan to also if there is some new input execute only that.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1)  `$(OUTDIR)/%` is dependent on `$(OUTFILE)` (which is a list of all outfiles).  Therefore if you change any one of the `OUTFILE`s, you make everything in `$(OUTDIR)/%` obsolete.   I believe what you want is this:

```
$(OUTDIR)/%_R1_001.fastq.gz: $(RDIR)/%_R2_001.fastq.gz
    .... (rules to make out/R1 from raw/R2

$(RDIR)/%_R2_001.fastq.gz: $(RDIR)/%_R1_001.fastq.gz
    .... (rules to make R2 from R1
```

This makes each file dependent only on the files that effect it.

2) you have the target `all` dependent on `$(OUTDIR)` which is a directory.  If you use parallel make, it may generate the `$(OUTDIR)` *after* it generates the other dependencies of `all:` (some of which would depend on $(OUTDIR) being created).     What you want there is to remove `all`'s dependency on `$(OUTDIR)`, and add the line:

```
$(OUTFILE) : | $(OUTDIR)
```

Notice the `|`, which means order only (don't consider `$(OUTFILE)` out of date if `$(OUTDIR)` is newer.   This is important, as a directory's timestamp is updated each time a file in the directory is changed, and so it tends to be newer than its contents.

Comment: thanks for the help. I don't understand the 1) point. Do you suggest to remove   `OUTFILE=$(patsubst %_R1_001.fastq.gz,%_R2_001.fastq.gz,$(RFILES))`?  the **OUTKAL** variable how can  re-write as you suggest?

Comment: In your example, you have all references to `OUTKAL` commented out, so I was ignoring it.   I'm assuming the following:  The `$(OUTFILE)` lists all files you wish to create.  The `$(OUTFILE)`s are generated by some intermediate files named `*_R2_001.fastq.gz`.   The intermediate files are generated from other files  in the $(RDIR) directory with names `*_R1_001.fastq.gz`.    I gave you a rule to create the intermediate file, and the rule to convert the intermdiate file to the final file.   Then you do `all: $(OUTFILE)`, and make all, and you should get all the files in `$(OUTFILE)`.

Comment: sorry but I'm confused. thanks for you help and patience help.. Here you have the makefile [https://pastebin.com/Cudkmwad] and this is the error: [https://pastebin.com/nRnWZHDa]. @john